# How to get deviceID when using this device to scan barcode in javascript?

Tags: javascript, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to get the serial number of phone when using this phone to scan barcode. How I can do it.

The serial number should be unit.
I try using navigator of mdn `navigator.mediaDevices` but it is not unit, the result based on the different chrome.

Do we get the serial number when using this phone to scan barcode?

Thank you

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+phone+details+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. What do you mean by "unit" ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure browsers cannot access a phone's serial number. Your application runs in the browser, right? ("_the result based on the different chrome_")

Comment: You can only interrogate a phone from a signed app.

Comment: not sure I understand what you want. "barcode-scanner" suggests you want to use the phone to scan barcodes. One constraint is that your webpage where your code is loaded from needs to be `https` not `http`

Comment: the main reason I want to using javascript is get the serial number to use for an order feature in the webapp.